# Update data when using Remote Data after custom action?

Tags: material-table

I have a custom action that is making an API call to my backend to delete data from my database, this in turn removes the item that is being displayed from the database. How can I get the table data to update when this action is run?

This is from material-table issue [#457](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/457).

I initially thought to try to re-render the component using a setState change but that doesn't appear to be working. (i can see the state changing accordingly but the table never fetches the data again)

```
  {
                  icon: "delete",
                  tooltip: "Delete Partner",
                  onClick: (event, rowData) => {
                    console.log(rowData);
                    let data = {
                      entityId: rowData[0].entityId
                    };
                    fetch("/deleteEntity", {
                      method: "POST",
                      headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                      },
                      body: JSON.stringify(data)
                    }).then(response => {
                      if (response.status === 204) {
                        let index = currentSelectedRows.findIndex(
                          x => x.entityId === rowData[0].entityId
                        );
                        currentSelectedRows.splice(index, 1);
                        this.setState({ currentSelected: currentSelectedRows });
                        console.log("Partner Deleted");
                      } else if (response.status === 500) {
                        console.log("Something went wrong");
                      }
                    });
                  }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use tableRef and call onQueryChange manually. In this example button calls tables function. You can call it in your any action:

```js
class App extends Component {
  tableRef = React.createRef();

  state = {
      // set your initial data and columns here
  }

  render() {
    return (     
        <div style={{ maxWidth: '100%' }}>
              <MaterialTable
                tableRef={this.tableRef}
                columns={this.state.columns}
                data={this.state.data}
                title="Demo Title"             
              />
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              this.tableRef.current.onQueryChange();
            }}
          >
            ok
          </button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Apologies for the late response, would this also work if the initial set data was being pulled remotely? My data is using the `data={query => ` as described [here](https://mbrn.github.io/material-table/#/docz-examples-14-example-remote-data)

Comment: Shouldn't the prop be tableRef instead of ref?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to re-render the table by basically unmouting the the table.
Here is an example:

```
class MyStateComp extends React.Component {
  state = { loading: false }

  handleDelete = (event, rowData) => {
    this.setState({ loading: true })
    simulateAsyncDelete(event, rowData)
      .then(() => this.setState({loading: false}))
  }

  render() {
    loading
    ? <div>loading...</div>
    : <MaterialTable
        {/* other props */}
        actions={[
          {
            icon: 'delete',
            tooltip: 'Delete User',
            onClick: this.handleDelete
          }
        ]}
    />
  }
}
```

I tried to force an update with `this.forceUpdate` but it didn't work, my guess is that the data is fetch on the `componentDidMount` state which is very limiting :(